# How make related insert and update in one transaction?

Tags: graphql, hasura

Imagine two tables:

```
People {
 id: uuid
 home_id: uuid
}

Homes {
 id: uuid
}
```

Table **People** is already populated. What I would like to do, is to insert a new **Home** and update **home_id** field in the **People** table at the same time. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by creating a **HomeOwnership** table `{ person_id: uuid, home_id: uuid }` and removing `home_id` from the **People** table. Then I established foreign key relationships between the tables. Then the mutation would look like following:

```
mutation MyMutation($person_id: uuid = "some_id") {
  insert_home_one(object: {home_membership: {data: {person_id: $person_id}}}) {
    id
    home_membership{
      person{
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```